In Unicode why क़ is excluded from composition, whereas Å is not?
I was going through Unicode Normalization Forms, and saw that devanagari letter क़ is excluded from composition under Script-specific Exclusions, whereas latin letter Å is not. What is the reason behind this?

I am voting to reopen. Unicode seems programming-related enough and an answer for the rationale given in the standardisation process would also not be opinion-based.

@user17732522 I agree that it's ontopic, however i would consider voting to close as opinion-only, as I don't thinkn we can do anything but speculate on the "why" without being one of the authors of the norm. So, in the end, the question is not really about a solvable programming question, but on theoretical normalization design decision.

This is not an opinion-based or unknowable question. The older versions of #15 explain the reason, even using Å as their example. As with so many things in Unicode, the answer is "essentially for compatibility with certain pre-existing standards." I think the reason क़ is excluded is fairly clear; it would be awkward to break up the letter, since it's really a proper (even if foreign) "letter." Much like you don't compose the dots Arabic (including foreign sound indicators). While Å is a letter in some languages, it's also the symbol for Angstrom, in which case it really is "combined."

In newer versions of #15, the explanation of the Angstrom sign has been move to section 1.2. (Sourav, forgive me if I've misunderstood the common uses of क़. I study Devanagari for text layout and linguists purposes. I don't actually read any languages in the script. But I think I'm correct that the extra dot is thought of as a separate letter, rather than a ka-with-dot.)

"The character U+0958 (क़) DEVANAGARI LETTER QA is an example of a script-specific composition exclusion" https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/#:~:text=The%20character%20U%2B0958%20(%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BC,and%20unchanged%20since%20that%20version.

@CharlotteBuff pointed out in a comment my answer that my reasoning here is backwards, and they're correct. I've deleted my answer, but wanted to copy their comment here in case they don't come back: "since these decisions were made so long ago it doesn’t seem like the relevant documents are available online. It might be a good idea to ask on the Unicode mailing whether anyone still remembers."

The underlying point (that I messed up) is that ka+nukta is prevented from being composed into qa, even though DEVANAGARI LETTER QA exists. I expect this is due to the history of the encoding that Unicode absorbed from Devanagari. But as CharlotteBuff notes, the specific reason isn't clear from this document.

@Luuk "The list of script-specific composition exclusions constituted a one-time adjustment to the Unicode Normalization Algorithm, defined at the time of the composition version in 2001 and unchanged since that version." This does not answer why part at all. It just answers when. After reading this section only I asked this question.

@RobNapier to my best knowledge, क़ is not a completely new letter. The dot attached below (called nukta) is a diacritic, much like grave, acute and circumflex accents in latin scripts. It changes the pronounciation of क a little. It is not present in the original hindi alphabet. It is mainly used when writing loan words from urdu etc.

@SouravKannanthaB I haven't seen a definitive answer, so what follows is predominantly supposition. My understanding is that the atomic characters with nuqta are inherited from ISCII 1988 and only the three Dravidian consonants ऩ, ऱ, and ऴ. and a combining nuqta are in ISCII 1991. For round trip compatibility its necessary to use decomposed sequences rather than atomic characters for most cases with nuqta. For most of the characters in Unicode with nuqta the NFC (composed form) is actually the decomposed sequence. Except for ऩ, ऱ, and ऴ .

"In order to round-trip to an older standard" is definitely a common cause of strange rules in Unicode. So certainly seems reasonable.

The so-called script-specific composition exclusions are characters for which the generally preferred representation in actual usage is their fully decomposed form. The decisions about composition exclusions were all made in the late 90s so concrete information is hard to come by, but Robin Leroy on the Unicode mailing list managed to find two documents from 2001 that might explain why the Devanagari letters with nukta in the range U+0958..U+095F are excluded.
L2/01-304 is a collection of feedback from various Indian experts. The section on Devanagari states in reference to the characters encoded at U+0958..U+095F:

Usage of these code-points be discouraged, and rather use the
corresponding DEVANAGARI LETTER followed by Nukta sign 093C to
generate sounds in Urdu, Sindhi etc. For example
0958 क़ ≡ 0915 क 093c ◌़

L2/01-305 is a response to this feedback by Unicode representative Rick McGowan. It states in reference to the nukta letters:

The document proposes to discourage the use of these precomposed
characters with nuktas. By putting them into the composition
exclusions list, UTC has already excluded them from the Form C
normalization.

It can be assumed that the Unicode Consortium was already aware of similar feedback from Indian delegates back when the composition exclusion list was being finalised. In the meeting notes from UTC #78 held in late 1998, Ken Whistler explains that Hebrew experts also prefer full decomposition, and Hebrew is another script whose letters with diacritics are composition-excluded, giving credence to this theory.
The characters encoded at U+0958..U+095F did not exist as atomic letters in ISCII and weren’t strictly needed for roundtrip compatibility. As such there would have been little benefit for users of the Unicode Devanagari encoding to have the composed forms of these letters in their data.
